# Python: How do I multiply specific elements in an array by each other?

Tags: python, arrays

```
shoppingBasket = [['space ship'][2.25][3]]
```

The code above shows an imaginary shopping basket that shows the item (space ship), its cost (£2.25), and how many I am buying (3). How do I only multiply 2.25 by 3 to get the total cost of space ships to get £6.75 and how do I make that scalable? For example, maybe I also add 2 toy trains each costing £4.55?

Comment: Please display your desired output and also correct your variable assignment.

Comment: Presumably, all of that is a string, right? Because that literal, the way it's written now, results in a `TypeError`. Is this schema one you came up with, or are you forced to use it for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a list for this kind of thing? Use dictionaries inside of a list like

I have provided the code.

```
a = [
  {
    "product" : "space ship",
    "price" : 2.25,
    "quantity" : 3
  }
]

for i in a:
  print(i["Product"],":",(i["price"]*i["quantity"]))
```

and then running through a for loop and calculating it will be something good. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider creating a class called `Product` and it will contain the information about each of the product the user tries to put in the shopping basket. This is an example for a list of `Product` with a helper to get the cost of each `Product`:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    
    def get_total_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
        
shopping_basket = [Product("space ship", 2.25, 3), Product("toothbrush", 10, 5)]
total_cost_in_basket = 0
for product in shopping_basket:
    total_cost_in_basket = total_cost_in_basket + product.get_total_cost()
    
print("The total cost is", total_cost_in_basket)
```